# Validate presence of radio buttons - Show error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand that the best way to validate a radio button is using the `inclusion` validation, which is what I have done:

```
validates :gender,
    inclusion: { in: %w(Male Female),
    message: "Value must be male or female" }
```

However, I want it to show the validation "can't be blank" when neither radio button has been selected.

Right now if I submit the form with neither of them selected, I get no error.  Every other fields has the "can't be blank" error showing to the right of it.

How can I achieve this?  Or at least make the "Value must be male or female" show up when neither are selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
presence: { message: "foo" }
```

to your validation, the validation will also check that at least something is selected, and give a custom message in case of failure

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it doesn't.

Comment: I assume gender is in your database? Migration succeeded? If so, I would add a "if: :test" check to your validation, using a test method, so that you can see whether indeed that test method is called, and as such your validation. If your form is succesfully submitted, what value is in gender? nil or male/female? In other words - is your view submitting some default, even if you don't select anything at all?

Comment: There is no default value. When I check what gets submitted when I don't check anything off, I don't even see an empty hash for the attribute Gender. Literally nothing is there. Very strange.